# When Insert Press Name Tech Id Take Wrong Number Where Press Name Exist?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2012, t-sql, temporary-tables

I work on `SQL server 2017` I have table `#Pressfeature` as below

```
create table #Pressfeature
  (
  PartId int,
  PressName varchar(300),
  TechId int
  )
   insert into #Pressfeature(PartId,PressName,TechId)
   values
   (1211,'AC',1),
   (2421,'grail',2),
   (6211,'compress',3)
```

my issue Done For `Part id 3900` it take wrong

`TechId` 5 and Correct Must be 2 Because Press Name Exist as `Press Name  grail`.

If `Press Name` Not Exist it will Take `Maximum Number + 1` meaning 4 as `Press Name Angit`

```
   +--------+--------------+---------------+-------------
    | PartID |  PressName   |   TechId  
    +--------+--------------+---------------+-------------
    |   3900 | grail        |   2 (Exist Before )
    +--------+--------------+---------------+-------

   +--------+--------------+---------------+-------------
    | PartID |  PressName   |   TechId  
    +--------+--------------+---------------+-------------
    |   8321 | Angit        |   4 (New and Not Exist)
    +--------+--------------+---------------+-------
```

what I try is

```
 insert into #Pressfeature(PartId,PressName,TechId)
select  PartId,PressName,
        TechId  =  dense_rank() over (order by PressName)
                      + (select max(TechId) from #Pressfeature)
from    
(
        values
        (3900,'grail',NULL),
        (8321,'Angit',NULL)
) s (PartId,PressName,TechId)
```

Expected Result After Insert Data

```
PartId FeatureName TechnologyId
3900 grail         2
8321 Angit         4
```

Comment: Duplicate at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72584146/part-id-3900-take-wrong-technology-id-as-7-and-it-must-be-2-because-feature-name/72584401#72584401)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to keep the `TechId` for different `PartIds` with an existing `PressName`.
If that is what you want, I think you're missing a reference to the original table - the way the query is written, it will only calculate the new TechId rather than reuse the existing one. To do that, you can `LEFT JOIN` to the original table on  the `PressName` and then `COALESCE` the inserted `TechId`.

Like this:

```
select  s.PartId,s.PressName,
        TechId = COALESCE
        (
           pf.TechId,
           dense_rank() over (order by s.PressName) + (select max(TechId) from #Pressfeature)
        )
from    
(
        values
        (3900,'grail',NULL),
        (8321,'Angit',NULL)
) s (PartId,PressName,TechId)
LEFT JOIN #Pressfeature pf ON pf.PressName = s.PressName;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=06db84497ce36f34d1cd42005412d05e) here

Comment: yes thanks solved issue